# How to let Apple get logged into a closed environment on Citrix during app review?

Tags: ios, security, environment, citrix

Our organization and our environments run at closed environments (behind Citrix and no public access given to mobile apps connected to those).

We have developed a mobile app for iOS, for one of these environments, which runs also with Blackberry Dynamics as IAM. The question is related to the sign-in request of Apple during the App Review process for a mobile app.

Since we simply can not just open our environment to the public, we can not make the app accessible during app review (so they simply will not reach our server if they run the iPA). We are probably not the first organization who runs at closed environments and who experienced this issue.

I thougt self to;
1 - dynamic runtime urll; we can create sandbox environment and use this url and prod url behind another generic url of the loadbalancer or so. while in review we can forward traffic coming from the runtime url to sandbox env and after that we can toggle the traffic to prod url. this is compliancy wise hard to achieve within the organization.

Any more ideas without comprimizing our closed envs?